# Black screen of death on Windows 10 Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have been getting black screen of death recently on Windows 10 while I am on a remote desktop session and unfortunately the only option out of it is to  hard restart the machine.
I have tried many different ways from playing with remote desktop options to manipulating registry keys but nothing worked out for me.
I tried most of the suggested workarounds in the following link and updated the graphic cards drivers on both machines as well.
[Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connects with Black Screen then Disconnects](https://superuser.com/questions/976290/windows-10-remote-desktop-connects-with-black-screen-then-disconnects)

- My client machine is running Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 21H1, OS
  Build 19043.1165
- My remote machine is running Windows 10 Pro, Version
  21H1, OS Build 19043.1165

I am not sure when it all started and what caused it but it was working perfectly fine before. I ran out of options and would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Have you looked in the system event logs?

Comment: Unfortunately there was nothing related to the issue in the logs when I inspected Windows Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems setting my screen not to turn off from Power & Sleep options, resolved my issue and I haven't got any black screen.

[image]