# Windows 10 - RDP Black screen if user is not logged on prior to connecting

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, black-screen-of-death

Good afternoon guys,

I have had this black screen while remoting into PCs in my domain before. Its always been fixed by waiting a few minutes or rebooting all involved machines. This one case is just weird, and it started to happen out of the blue. Onsite we use VNC to remote into Computers. That works Flawless, but we have remote users that use a VPN, and RDP to connect to their workstations.

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Windows 10 fully patched on both ends.

**ISSUE:**

- When using RDP to remotely connects to PC1 everything looks like it works except I get a black screen.
- This does not happens if the user is logged into the PC1(Meaning that the user cannot sign out locally on PC1. He would have to lock the screen, and then he would be able to RP in.)

I have already tried all the Display and Bitmap troubleshooting and it is not that. It looks like something is hanging while loading main screen.

Pleae help

Answer (score 0):

There's another thread that discusses answers in addition to the display and bitmap troubleshooting options you mention ([Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connects with Black Screen then Disconnects](https://superuser.com/questions/976290/windows-10-remote-desktop-connects-with-black-screen-then-disconnects)).

Ranges from downloading RDC Manager ,(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman) to pressing or triggering (if a VM) CTRL+ALT+DEL to bring up the login screen.

One answer mentions using group policy editor and disabling UDP, "Use the Group Policy Editor (or download the superior "Policy Plus"), and disable UDP. You can find this in policy rds/client or rds/host/connection/select protocols, or in the registry at SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\Client"

A server fault post discusses a similar problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/220437/remote-desktop-connection-screen-is-totally-black-but-server-is-working-perfectl, but points to a Microsoft KB article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/a-black-screen-appears-while-sign) that mentions the symptoms and resolution:

> Symptoms
> While sign in into a remote server by using remote desktop, the following issues may occur:

> A slow sign-in process.

> A black screen appears for a while, until the regular desktop appears.

> Resolution
> Disable the use of Bitmap Caching on the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) >client.

> Verify that the server, client, and the network equipment using the "MTU" >size.

In my experience, these types of issues can be somewhat hit or miss and it may be worth checking event viewer to see if there's another, unforeseen underlying issue. But, when using RDP, if I encounter the issue and in the interest of time, the typical remedial action is to try ctrl+alt+del, try and access the task manager to re-run explorer.exe or reboot the offending computer.

Hopefully that helps.