# RDP: Black screen

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I got a problem that I've spend most of today trying to fix, but unable to. I connect remotely to a computer, which is running Windows 10, but eventually it stops working. I can fix it with a reboot, but not for long as the issue reappears.

**Issue:** It will just show a black screen for 30 seconds or so (not responsive no matter what I do) and then say "failed to reconnect to your remote session".

Sometimes it works when I use Teamviewer, even though RDP is all black screen. Sometimes I can force a screen on one of them, by connecting both at the same time. Sometimes neither of them will work.

I'm using ZeroTier as VPN tunnel for RDP. I can ping all internal network IPs without drops, as long as I deactivate the firewall.

The only errors I can find in Event Viewer are these:

> 'Failed CreateVirtualChannel call on this Connections Stack' in
> CUMRDPConnection::CreateVirtualChannel at 2958 err=[0xd0000001]

and

> 'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection::QueryProperty at
> 3344 err=[0x80004001]

**I have tried:**

- disabling UDP and RemoteFX
- all my drivers are up-to-date
- Nvidia Overlay fixed
- tried using a different router and different adapter (ethernet/wifi).

**Any other ideas?**

Comment: Sounds (a bit) like https://superuser.com/questions/976290/windows-10-remote-desktop-connects-with-black-screen-then-disconnects

Comment: Your connecting device is running what?

Comment: @Gantendo I've already read through that and tried all - still doesn't work

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat It happens on both MacOS and Windows 10. Right now I can connect on my iPhone, but can't connect from my MacOS and Windows 10 computers.

Comment: @bigtuna152 Edit the question and include what you've tried so far. Beets, bears and Battlestar Galactica.